# How to get ipfix working with openvswitch?

Tags: monitoring, netflow

I'm trying to monitor my [OpenVswitch](http://openvswitch.org/) via [IPFix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_Flow_Information_Export). But I'm banging my head against a brick wall for two days now :/

According to the [ovs-vsctl manpage](http://openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/ovsman.cgi?page=utilities/ovs-vsctl.8) I need to add a new entry into the config-database, more precisely into the "ipfix"-table. That worked pretty well, and it looks like I got it right:

```
# ovs-vsctl list ipfix
_uuid               : 2d54982b-6cc5-4a8c-845c-cc7ef701da01
external_ids        : {}
obs_domain_id       : 123
obs_point_id        : 456
sampling            : 64
targets             : ["<collector-ip>:<port>"]
```

I then downloaded [libIPFIX](http://libipfix.sourceforge.net/) and started the example_collector. But nothing shows up. I don't receive any information. I confirmed it using wireshark ...

Some Google-Research brought up an [eMail](http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/dev/2013-January/024629.html) from the Mailinglist, which states that one needs

> OpenFlow actions to cause IPFIX to be sent to the collectors

According to this [eMail](http://openvswitch.org/pipermail/git/2013-April/003876.html) there are new "sample actions", but I couldn't find any further information how to add them.

My best guess is that I'm missing these OpenFlow Sample-Actions. Can anybody provide me with information how to add those?

**/edit:**
I'm running OpenVswitch Version 1.11.0 on openSUSE 13.1 (x86_64).

To get IPFix to work I tried the following:

```
# ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge s1 ipfix=@i -- --id=@i create IPFIX targets=\"10.0.0.1:4739\" obs_domain_id=123 obs_point_id=456 sampling=64
2d54982b-6cc5-4a8c-845c-cc7ef701da01
```

To confirm that I did the ovs-vsctl list ipfix (see above)

A similar command worked as expected to get sFlow to work:

```
# ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge s1 sflow=@sflow -- --id=@sflow create sflow agent=eth0  target=\"10.0.0.1:6343\" header=128 sampling=32 polling=2
0df2b92b-8a83-4a63-acc4-fecf6f8f492f
```

Right after entering that line, I got sampling results send to my target computer. Unfortunately no luck with IPFix.

Comment: @ChristophHaefner What are your log files saying when you pass the failing IPFix command?

Comment: @Fizzle: Thanks a million for the hint. I was search previously for log-files, but /var/log/openvswitch/ was empty, so I moved on. But with your push I searched more sophisticated and found a log-file: /var/log/ovs-vswitchd.log! And it's actually stating that he tries to deliver: "2014-01-22T10:09:04Z|1017630|collectors|WARN|sending to collector failed: Connection refused" Must have overlooked it while debugging with wireshark :/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The verbiage you're using to setup IPFix is definately right.

This is what you have:

```
ovs-vsctl -- set Bridge s1 ipfix=@i -- --id=@i create IPFIX targets=\"10.0.0.1:4739\" obs_domain_id=123 obs_point_id=456 sampling=64
```

And pretty much the same [example](http://openvswitch.org/cgi-bin/ovsman.cgi?page=utilities%2Fovs-vsctl.8) is outlined in the ovs-vsctl man file:

```
IPFIX

Configure bridge br0 to send one IPFIX flow record per packet sample to UDP port 4739 on host 192.168.0.34, with Observation Domain ID 123 and Observation Point ID 456:

ovs−vsctl −− set Bridge br0 ipfix=@i −− −−id=@i create IPFIX targets=\"192.168.0.34:4739\" obs_domain_id=123 obs_point_id=456
```

Based on your log file in the comments section:

```
2014-01-22T10:09:04Z|1017630|collectors|WARN|sending to collector failed: Connection refused
```

I think it would be resonable to assume the collector (`10.0.0.1`) is misconfigured or something is preventing connections inbound to it.

Comment: You are 100% right with your assumption. I never thought about it because I'm using the example_collector from libipfix (which is supposed to be the reference-implementation).

Comment: I quickly wrote a little programm listening on the 4739-port and just dumping what he gets on screen. Debugging that with Wireshark again brings one important thing up: The Exporter doesn't send a template :/ Might also be the reason why the example collector refuses what he gets ...

Comment: What are you using for flow collection/analyzing?

Comment: @Fizzle I'm using http://libipfix.sourceforge.net/

Comment: What are you using for sFlow collection? I'm convinced your OpenVswitch configurations are correct, but I'm not certain about your collection system. I found an [IETF pdf](http://trac.tools.ietf.org/group/irtf/trac/raw-attachment/wiki/NetworkManagementResearchGroupAg%26LgMunich/nmrg-25-novotny_part_003.pdf) that recommends NfSen (nfdump backend) for flow collection and parsing. Would you be able to try nfdump, instead? I'm not trying to mask the problem, I just can't find a lot of documentation on libipfix. Searching `nfdump setup` nets a significantly larger amount of results.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will look into it.
I found the mistake by now: The example_collector from libipfix is listening on tcp:4739, while OpenVswitch was sending it out on udp:4739. I didn't see it in wireshark, because I was adding a filter "tcp.port == 4739" ...
I was missing the template because it was send once at the very beginning and I stopped wireshark several times and restartet the scan without saving.

Comment: By restarting everything and start plane from scratch I got everything working now. I see the data coming in and wireshark can explain every field of every packet.
Thanks to all of you, you earned some good karma for helping a desperate man :)

Comment: @ChristophHaefner, thank you for a good question.  Please consider asking again if the need arises